# Saxonica URI Resolver

Tags: xslt, saxon

we have xslt file which have multiple xsl:include /document, i am caching XsltExecutable object (the compiled xsl) and same used for transformation by multiple threads.

my question is, do we need to provide URIResolver during **the compilation as well as executing transformation**?, compiled style sheet (XsltExecutable object) does not include all related/dependent style sheets?.

in my case i am getting error if i do not provide URIResolver in both places. is there anyway we can keep XsltExecutable of common xsls and include it during compilation/execution phase of other xslts.

**Note**: we are using saxonica EE

```
public void transform(XsltExecutable stylesheet,Map<String, String> formatterMap, String sourceXMl, String outFileName) throws SaxonApiException {

       Processor processor = new Processor(true);
       Serializer out = processor.newSerializer(new File(outFileName + ".xml"));
       out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.METHOD, "xml");
       out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.INDENT, "yes");

       Xslt30Transformer trans = stylesheet.load30();
       trans.setURIResolver(new CigURIResolver(formatterMap));
       trans.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(sourceXMl)), out);
       System.out.println("Output written to out.xml");

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `URIResolver` on the `XsltCompiler` is used primarily for resolving compile-time `xsl:include` and `xsl:import` declarations. The `URIResolver` on the `XsltTransformer` is used primarily for resolving run-time calls on the `doc()` and `document()` functions.

An `XsltExecutable` represents an entire compiled stylesheet. If you want to compile different parts of a stylesheet independently of each other, and link the separately compiled parts together in different combinations, then you need to define it as a number of separate packages, using the new XSLT 3.0 constructs `xsl:package` and `xsl:use-package` (and not `xsl:import`/`xsl:include`). At the API level a compiled package is represented using an `XsltPackage` object.